# Jolt Spec for moving the json objects into the simple array

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am having an array of objects in the given format:

```
[
 {
  "meta": [
   {
    "id": "101A"
   },
   {
    "id": "101B"
   }
 ]
}
]
```

Can someone help me with jolt spec I want the final output in the following format:

```
[
  {
  "meta": [
    "101A",
    "101B",
    ......
   ]
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have a  Jolt Spec ??

Comment: No id don't, I am quite confused with this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to iterate over your two arrays using the "*", and when iterating over your second array (meta) just get the id attribute and send to the meta array (ignore the object). See if this helps you understand:

```
 [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "*": {
            "meta": {
              "*": {
                "id": "meta"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```